# Custom validate Annotation not used in java

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

I've created a custom annotation:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = BeginsWithACapitalLetterValidator.class)
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface BeginsWithACapitalLetter {
    String message() default "{Should begin with a capital!}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

}
```

Which is validated by:

```
public class BeginsWithACapitalLetterValidator implements ConstraintValidator<BeginsWithACapitalLetter, String> {

    @Override
    public void initialize(BeginsWithACapitalLetter constraintAnnotation) {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        String valueAsString = (String) value;
        System.out.println(valueAsString);
        if (valueAsString.length() > 0) {
            return Character.isUpperCase(valueAsString.charAt(0));
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Which I apply to a single field:

```
public class Person {

    @BeginsWithACapitalLetter
    private String forename;

    public String getForename() {
        return forename;
    }

    public void setForename(String forename) {
        this.forename = forename;
    }
}
```

I was hoping to test this using:

```
    @Test
    public void nameShouldFailValidationIfFirstLetterNotCapital() {
        // Given
        Person person = new Person();
        person.setForename("name");

        // When
        Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validate(person.getForename());

        // Then
        assertEquals(1, violations.size());
    }

    private Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> validate(Object obj) {
        ValidatorFactory validatorFactory = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory();
        Validator validator = validatorFactory.getValidator();
        return validator.validate(obj);
    }
```

But the test fails with no violations:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected: <1> but was: <0>

What am I missing?

---

Imports used:

```
'javax:javaee-api:7.0'
'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:5.1.3.Final'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to validate the person not the forename. So instead of

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validate(person.getForename());
```

use

```
Set<ConstraintViolation<Object>> violations = validate(person);
```

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping to have multiple fields in Person with different annotations on, If I validate on a "person" level I couple all my tests together, Is there a way I can avoid this or am I testing it the wrong way?

Comment: Also, when I use other validators such as @NotNull they seem to throw violations if I test them on a field level. Why is this case different?

Comment: You can use `validateProperty` or `validateValue` (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/5.2/api/) to validate single fields (with/without a specific value).

When you use `validate(person.getForename())`, the `validate` and hence the `Validator` only sees the String and not the Person (Strings don't have a reference to where they are used).

@NotNull may seem to work, since you are passing null to `validate`